# How to add items to array instead of overriding in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have the following code:

```
if(v == btn) {
    data.add(new String[]{txtCount.getText().toString() + txtTally.getText().toString()});
    System.out.println("Contents" + data);

    for(String[] str : data) {
        System.out.println("ArrayContents" + Arrays.toString(str));
        txtResults.setText(Arrays.toString(str));
    }
}
```

The first line creates an array of strings from my two `TextView` fields and adds them to an `ArrayList`.

The loop underneath is supposed to print out the contents of the array in order and display them to the user in another `TextView` every time the user hits a button. The code prints the correct values but doesn't keep adding to the array when the user clicks the button, it instead overwrites the previous values.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: use proper method of TextView instead setText

Comment: but why adding array to an arraylist? You can add them directly to arraylist

Comment: When do you initialize the variable 'data'?

Comment: Please add more code. Make sure you are not initializing the `ArrayList` in `onClick` method.

Comment: Adding the array to the arraylist because later I am exporting the results to a CSV file which takes an array of strings as its argument.

Comment: where do You have initialized Your ArrayList?

Comment: public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements SensorEventListener, OnClickListener {

private List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
private Button btn;

Comment: The `String[]` you're trying to add to `data` always contains one element. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String[] str : data) {
        System.out.println("ArrayContents" + Arrays.toString(str));
        txtResults.setText(Arrays.toString(str));
    }
```

You set the text of textview in a foreach loop, therefore the string shown in the textview only the last pair of string in the List.

Try append a string first in the loop then, add it to TextView, example:

```
String a;

 for(String[] str : data) {
            System.out.println("ArrayContents" + Arrays.toString(str));
            a+=(Arrays.toString(str));
        }

txtResults.setText(a);
```